# Why I can't find my appstoreconnect within my developer account being an account holder

Tags: apple-developer-account

When I try to open https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ it automatically redirects me to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/developers page instead of my apps page since I am the admin and account holder of the developer account.

Answer (score 2):

I found it myself since I am enrolled in the Apple developer enterprise account so it isn't possible to publish an application for public use from an enterprise account and you have to change it to the Apple developer program from the enterprise account. You can check the link for more clarity.
https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/